# I am getting "Cannot invoke method getProjectByName() on null object" when i run the project with LAUNCH RUNNER in soapUI

Tags: groovy, soapui

I have controller which takes the test data from excel in pass them into properties of another project called SERVICE_APP project .

Controller was running properly when i run it with testcase SoapUI . but i am getting error "getProjectByName() on null object"  when i run with commandline / soapUI from Project-launch / Testsuite launch.

```
16:20:53,896 ERROR [SoapUI] An error occurred [Cannot invoke method getProjectB
Name() on null object], see error log for details
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke method getProjectByName() on null
object
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.NullObject.invokeMethod(NullObject.java:
7)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.call(PogoMeta
lassSite.java:45)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallS
teArray.java:45)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.NullCallSite.call(NullCallSite.
ava:32)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallS
teArray.java:45)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractC
llSite.java:108)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractC
llSite.java:116)
        at Script1.run(Script1.groovy:159)
        at com.eviware.soapui.support.scripting.groovy.SoapUIGroovyScriptEngine
run(SoapUIGroovyScriptEngine.java:100)
        at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.teststeps.WsdlGroovyScriptTestStep.run(
sdlGroovyScriptTestStep.java:154)
        at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.support.AbstractTestCaseRunner.runTestS
ep(AbstractTestCaseRunner.java:239)
        at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.testcase.WsdlTestCaseRunner.runCurrentT
stStep(WsdlTestCaseRunner.java:52)
        at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.support.AbstractTestCaseRunner.internal
un(AbstractTestCaseRunner.java:152)
        at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.support.AbstractTestCaseRunner.internal
un(AbstractTestCaseRunner.java:47)
        at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.support.AbstractTestRunner.run(Abstract
estRunner.java:139)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: Does this help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/28303050/3124333

Comment: Hey SiKing,
Sorry , it does not help me , i have tried it . i kept controller testsuite in project itself , still it is giving error to me

Comment: I guess the only thing left is: step to reproduce, because a stack trace with no code is pretty useless. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Hi @SiKing :  I have added the code also 
Please have a look once and help me.

Comment: Please read this https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve again, and follow the instructions!

Comment: @SiKing : This is helped me to solve this issuehttp://forum.soapui.org/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=1449

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We need to load project manual when we are running from commandline/ launch runner

http://forum.soapui.org/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=1449

This is due to the fact that there is no Workspace when running from command line, so you can't access other projects in this way. To be able to access another project, you need to manually load it. This can be done within the groovy script using the ProjectFactoryRegistry.

```
import com.eviware.soapui.model.project.ProjectFactoryRegistry
import com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.WsdlProjectFactory

def workspace = testRunner.testCase.testSuite.project.workspace
def testProject = (workspace==null) ? 
  ProjectFactoryRegistry.getProjectFactory(WsdlProjectFactory.WSDL_TYPE).createNew("<path to your project>.xml") :
  workspace.getProjectByName("ViewingCardManager_v15B4.0")
if(!testProject.open && workspace!=null) workspace.openProject(testProject)

testProject.properties["mqResponse"].value = "blahblah"
```

@Siking : thanks for trying to give solution